# How to select from cursor (or selection start) through the end of a Google Docs text document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to figure out how to use

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().setSelection(range);
```

in a Google Docs text document, to select all text from the current cursor position (or the beginning of the selection) through the end, but I don't understand how to create the necessary [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range) object to do this.

(References: [`setSelection`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#setSelection(Range)),  [`Document`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document))

There is a helpful [cursor inspector](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/06/introducing-google-docs-cursorselection.html) available from this [issue-post](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2865), which makes it clear that the "offset" of a selection is relative to the *current paragraph* (or technically, [`Element`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element)) that it's in. So if the selection is the first five characters in list element three, then its offsets are 0 and 4, with no real context of the elements (paragraphs) before it or after it.

[image: inspector screenshot]

Selecting through the end of the document (I've added in some empty paragraphs after the list):

[image: inspector screenshot]

The closest thing I've found is [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#newRange()), which increases the selection to include every table in the document.

```
// Change the user's selection to a range that includes every table in the document.
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
var tables = doc.getBody().getTables();
for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
   rangeBuilder.addElement(tables[i]);
}
doc.setSelection(rangeBuilder.build());
```

So, how do you use [`RangeBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-builder.html) to create a [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range) that starts with the "current cursor position" (or start of the current selection), and ends with "document end"?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want select everything from the current cursor position to the end of the whole document?

Comment: @teatimer Yes. That's exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var rangeBuilder = doc.newRange();
  var currentElement = doc.getCursor().getElement();
  rangeBuilder.addElement(currentElement);
  var sibling = currentElement.getNextSibling();
  while (sibling !== null) {
    rangeBuilder.addElement(sibling);
    sibling = sibling.getNextSibling();
  }
  doc.setSelection(rangeBuilder.build());
```

---

@teatimer,

Your answer seems to be on the right track! Here's [the document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WKC7us0S1hxTdVvWMMw-zlDTEgCHaShsPJjRZ0Mzh2o/edit) I'm using. I've put some diagnostics below. I hope it helps.

(Forgive the edit for this response. It is really not the purpose of editing answers, but there's too much information for a comment. Feel free to delete this after you're done with it.)

---

With the cursor at the very top, it works:

[image: screenshot]

Same if the cursor is in an empty line in the middle, at column zero:

[image: screenshot]

If the cursor is between the very first and second characters in the document, when you run the command, it selects only the current paragraph:

[image: screenshot]

Selecting the first character in the document results in an error:

[image: screenshot]

As does any selection, it seems:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please see my edit at the end of your answer. It seems to be the beginning of what I need! Thank you.

Comment: You can use getSelection() if you need to get a selection. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getSelection()

Comment: @aliteralmind I believe `var currentElement = doc.getCursor().getElement();` will cause an exception if `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();` is truthy.